# how to build a project with angular 5 and sails.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, angular-cli, angular5

I'm new in sails and I want to build an app with angular 5, sails and 'PostgreSQL'. I need a good reference to learn it. I searched a lot but I didn't find a good reference.